# How can I change the value of nodes returned by an XPath query?

Tags: xpath

For example, I need my results to be of the form

```
<result>
  <French>
    <country>country-name</country>
    <country>country-name</country>
    ...
  </French>
  <German>
    <country>country-name</country>
    <country>country-name</country>
    ...
  </German>
</result>
```

but currently, my results are of the form

```
  <language percentage="100">German</language>
  <language percentage="32">French</language>
  <language percentage="1">German</language>
  <language percentage="100">French</language>
  <language percentage="100">French</language>
  <language percentage="100">German</language>
  <language percentage="99">French</language>
  <language percentage="100">French</language>
  <language percentage="10">French</language>
  <language percentage="32">German</language>
  <language percentage="100">French</language>
  <language percentage="18">French</language>
  <language percentage="65">German</language>
```

This is my query:

```
 doc("countries.xml")//country/language[contains(text(), "French") or contains(text(), "German")]
```

The original data looks like this:

```
<country name="Afghanistan" population="22664136" area="647500">
    <language percentage="11">Turkic</language>
    <language percentage="35">Pashtu</language>
    <language percentage="50">Afghan Persian</language>
</country>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XQuery, this will solve the problem:

```
  <result>
  {
    for $language in distinct-values(doc("countries.xml")//language)
    return
      element {translate($language, " ", "_")}
      {
        for $country in doc("countries.xml")//country[language = $language]
        return element country {string($country/@name)}
      }
  }
  </result>
```

Please note that the language cannot be used as a tag name right away, because it contains spaces (as in "Afghan Persian") - thus the invocation of `translate`.

In case you just want the languages that you named, replace the `for` clause by

```
    for $language in ("French", "German")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use LinQ to XML/Object, create a query with GroupBy and rewrite the XML with XMLWriter or use XML StyleSheet Transform with xml/xsl together.

Answer (score 0):

XPath can only select nodes in your input document. If you want to construct a new output document, you can do this using XSLT or XQuery, both of which use XPath to select nodes from the input, and add facilities to construct new nodes in the output.